# How to delete the Knowledge base from my terminal?

Tags: genexus

If I want to completely delete a created KB due to, for example, PC space issues, is there a proper procedure?

For example, is it OK to delete only the directories that exist in the KB directory under Model, or if it is also necessary to delete the KB data on SQLServer, I would like to know the rough procedure.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeneXus does not have a native way of deleting knowledge bases.

There is a script to delete KB and several of the artifacts created, such as database, webapps, virtual directories, etc.

You can read https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?42567,Remove+Knowledge+Base
and download the script from https://github.com/sebagomez/scripts/blob/master/ps/remove-knowledgebase.ps1